# Get application name from Windows XP cut and paste?

Tags: java, windows-xp, clipboard

This is a bit of a long shot, but if anyone can figure it out, you guys can...

In Windows XP, is there any meta-data that comes with a cut and paste action, from which I can ascertain the application that provided the clipboard contents?

Bonus question... if there is such information, is there any way I can access it through a Java app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the clipboard format. If it is plain-text, then no. Unless you want to install global hooks on the clipboard.

Which you cannot do from Java.

Answer (score 2):

The API function GetClipboardOwner returns the clipboard owner 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649041(VS.85).aspx), -sorry cannot mark as link because the "()" in the URL-

Don't know Java, I suppose you can call native API functions from inside the Java VM.

A "quick and dirty" approach could be using an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to intercept the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>INS</kbd> hotkeys, grab the id of the active process (in a file or any place that can be accessed by the Java app) and proceed with the clipboard copy. The AutoHotKey part shouldn't be difficult, don't know about the Java part.